# Multiple html pages in Uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, html, ipad

I have multiple html pages, i need to navigate from one page to other page via scrolling. 
if i use  web views inside a scrollview the above requirement can be solved.
But it is not a good practice according to apple and also lots of scrolling issues may occur.
Can anyone know me any alternative solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue using Uipageviewcontroller. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView. Add gesture recognizers to webview.
On recognizing a particular required gesture, perform your action of navigating to a different site.

Comment: Actually, adding gesture recognizers to `UIWebView` and inserting it into `UIScrollView` lead to the same kind of problems relative to handling gestures (`UIWebView` has a lot of private gesture recognizers) and scrolling accordingly (there is also a bunch of private subviews inside a `UIWebView`). If you can get away with it depends partly on the webpage content (if it doesn't have to scroll, it works better). Also if you use gesture recognizers, you will probably have to implement the delegate method `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and return `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the bottom of your view while scrolling you can call a function to append a new webview.
If you are loading HTML pages made by server side, you can load a javascript when you reache the bottom. In this case the appending part will be done by server side

Go through webview delegate [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

(You can do whatever you wish in that function, for example appending a new webview or navigate to a new one)